# mysql DATE datatype's default value not working

Tags: mysql

I do have a column named `leave_date` in my mysql table.

This is how I create it.

```
leave_date DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00'
```

It was ok in my earlier mysql versions, but now I have 5.7 and when I try to create above table, I can get an error.

Message look like this:

> ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'leave_date'

Can anybody tell me what would be the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: You didn't required set default value just leave blank it automatically take '0000-00-00'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem is that you are not using a valid date.

The minimum valid date in MySQL is `'1000-01-01'` , each RDBMS usually have its own minimum date value. Oracle is `0001-01-01` and SQL-Server is `01/01/1753` .

**EDIT:** By the error you are receiving , I believe you also have time value in this column? Try changing it to datetime

```
ALTER TABLE employees MODIFY leave_date DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '1000-10-01'
```

Or update the table and trunc the time value yourself, and then use your alter command.

Comment: I tried it, but then I can get `mysql> ALTER TABLE employees MODIFY leave_date DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '1000-10-01';
ERROR 1265 (01000): Data truncated for column 'leave_date' at row 1`

Comment: There is not any values in that column. Anyway I tried with `datetime` but I can get the same error message as above comment

Comment: How is this column currently defined ? @user3733831

Comment: Something like this `leave_date DATE DEFAULT NULL`

Comment: Well, if its empty, why don't you just drop it, and add it again with the new configuration ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is document from official [site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html).(Mysql 5.7)

> The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part. MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'.

`0000-00-00` is not in range `1000-01-01` to `9999-12-31`.

Comment: I tried with a date of `1000-01-01`. But it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @user3733831 Does this default value have some special meaning? If not, why don't you use current date?

Answer (score 1):

That is because of server SQL Mode - [NO_ZERO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date).

From the reference:

> NO_ZERO_DATE - In strict mode, don't allow '0000-00-00' as a valid date. You can still insert zero dates with the IGNORE option. When not in strict mode, the date is accepted but a warning is generated.

Comment: interesting. I did not knew about this flag